# Compiling Izpack project

Tags: java, eclipse, izpack

I'm trying to build the Izpack project in Eclipse to add my own panels. 
I was able to build the sample provided on the command line, but not in eclipse.

I've read the documentation and I'm still a bit confused.
My questions, does the actual Izpack source code have to be included with the project (if so which components and where) or is it enough to have the install.xml ? 
I've set up the debug config like the doc says but Eclipse can't find the compiler class to run.

Answer (score 1):

Hello 
In the link below you will find a nice help about izpack installer.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=89

Link below contains a detailed pdf to make installer with izpack.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?attachment_id=112

cheers
Imran tariq

Answer (score 1):

I managed to build the izpack project as follows

- Checkout as java project
- On 'Run configurations' make a Maven Build (eclipse m2e plugin). On workspace
  select the root directory of the checked out project and on Goals put 'clean install'

I managed to build working izpack up to 5.0.6 with this way.

Comment: Or you can import the source code in eclipse File -> Import -> Existing maven projects -> Select pom files

Comment: Running some tests may fail because it needs administration privileges.